# Awk script fails when run using exec, but not when run manually

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, awk

I'm using a couple of awk scripts for reading/writing my network interfaces files. In order to integrate these scripts into my Node.js project, I'm executing them using the child_process.exec function.

The problem is the read script seems to act different depending on whether it is being run using exec or not.

Here is my code for running the script in Node:

```
import cp from "child_process";
import {normalize, join} from "path";

const local = (path) => normalize(join(__dirname, path));
const readScript = local("/network-scripts/read-interface.awk");
const writeScript = local("/network-scripts/write-interface.awk");

function exec(cmd, options) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    cp.exec(cmd, options, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if(error) reject(error);
      else resolve({stdout, stderr});
    });
  });
}

function read(interfacesPath, interfaceName) {
  return exec(`awk -f ${readScript} ${normalize(interfacesPath)} device=${interfaceName}`).then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  });
}
```

Here is the interfaces file I'm testing with:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0 eth1 eth2 eth3

iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.0.11.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.0.11.1

iface eth1 inet manual
    up ifconfig $IFACE 0.0.0.0 up
    down ifconfig $IFACE down

iface eth2 inet static
    address 192.168.1.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.254

iface eth3 inet dhcp
```

And here is my test:

```
import intf from "../server/interfaces";
const testInterfaces = `${__dirname}/../test-interfaces`;

describe("interfaces", () => {
  it("should be able to read a dynamic interface", (done) => {
    intf.read(testInterfaces, "eth3").then(() => done(), done);
  });
});
```

When I run this test, I get this error as the output:

```
Failed: { [Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c awk -f /Users/james1/Projects/pump-dashboard/server/network-scripts/read-interface.awk /Users/james1/Projects/pump-dashboard/test-interfaces device=eth3
]
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '/bin/sh -c awk -f /Users/james1/Projects/pump-dashboard/server/network-scripts/read-interface.awk /Users/james1/Projects/pump-dashboard/test-interfaces device=eth3' }
```

However if I copy the command directly out of that error:

```
awk -f /Users/james1/Projects/pump-dashboard/server/network-scripts/read-interface.awk /Users/james1/Projects/pump-dashboard/test-interfaces device=eth3
```

and run it in my terminal, it outputs "dhcp" as expected.

Additionally, if I run the `read` function with the input device as "eth0" which is a static interface, the script works as expected (even with exec).

Why would I receive different results when using exec vs running the command in my terminal (using zsh)? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Backticks in the js code? If that command in the error is *actually* what is being run then the problem is the lack of quotes around awk and its arguments. Try that *exact* command manually and you should see it fail too.

Comment: @EtanReisner the backticks are a new ES2015 thing - it's a string template.

Comment: It looks like it's trying to run the command via `sh -c`, but (if that error object can be trusted) it's not surrounding the whole command in quotes. *edit* no, that's just misleading error reporting.

Comment: The command that Node is *actually* running is `/bin/sh -c '<your command>'` so you might want to see whether that works from a shell prompt.

Comment: @Pointy You're right. When I run using `/bin/sh -c`, I receive `usage: awk [-F fs] [-v var=value] [-f progfile | 'prog'] [file ...]`. If I wrap the entire command after `/bin/sh -c` in quotes, it works, but I'm not sure how to instruct `exec` to do that.

Comment: @SimpleJ well I *think* it should be doing that; it's calling a lower-level API internally and it passes two separate arguments to the `/bin/sh` it spawns: `-c` as the first parameter and your command string as the second. (At the level of that API, quotes aren't necessary, as it's directly building the `argv` array basically.) It would be nice if Node could get you a better error message than, well, nothing at all it looks like.